# How to measure execution time of a cucumber step

Tags: ruby, cucumber, measure

I'm looking for a way to measure the execution time of my cucumber steps. Using the `junit` format I managed to get some data about the execution time of the features and scenarios, but I would like to see the times of the steps inside the scenarios as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cucumber --format usage
```

"Prints where step definitions are used. The slowest step definitions (with duration) are listed first."

Answer (score 0):

```
"-Dcucumber.options= -p usage"
```

This sorts the Step Definitions by their average execution time.